# Contact form 7 default option print as selected value in mail

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

```
[select my_select class:input class:styled "Select Options"   
"Option 1" "Option 2" "Option 3" "Option 4"]
```

*Question:*

How to prevent printing `'Select Options'` if user not selected any options in receiving email?
If user select first option `('Select Options')`,it should not print as `'Select Options'` in mail.

Comment: `<select> <option>Select Options</options><option value="opt-1"> Option 1</option><option value="opt-2"> Option 2</option></select>`

I need just like abouve in contact form 7.

Comment: This is right [in the docs](http://contactform7.com/checkboxes-radio-buttons-and-menus/). Like...this exact thing. It's right there.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`[select my_select first_as_label class:styled "Select Options" "Option 1" "Option 2" "Option 3" "Option 4"]`

Also, you can check the [documentation](https://contactform7.com/checkboxes-radio-buttons-and-menus/).

Answer (score 11):

Change your select tag to the following

```
[select my_select class:input class:styled include_blank "Option 1" "Option 2" "Option 3" "Option 4"]
```

The first option will have "---" as the text and a blank value, `<option value="">---</option>`

If you want to replace the text "---" with "Select Options" add the following code to functions.php

```
function my_wpcf7_form_elements($html) {
    $text = 'Select Option';
    $html = str_replace('---',  $text , $html);
    return $html;
}
add_filter('wpcf7_form_elements', 'my_wpcf7_form_elements');
```

Answer (score 2):

[select* BurjBestCompany default:get "The Best Advertising & Marketing Company" "The Best Airlines Company" ]

**BurjBestCompany**  should match with the query string name

For example:

```
http://example.com/?BurjBestCompany=The+Best+Advertising+%26+Marketing+Company
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Simple Solution to add Place Holder to select Drop Down Menu

```
[select* Test first_as_label "Placeholder" "Option 1" "Option 2"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This solutions worked exact how I wanted. so all the forms have consistency and the same default selected - you need to add the 'include_blank' on the field shortcode:

```
/**
 * Customize the default option selected on CF7
 */
 function my_wpcf7_form_elements($html) {
    $text = '—';
    $html = str_replace('---',  $text , $html);
    return $html;
}
add_filter('wpcf7_form_elements', 'my_wpcf7_form_elements');
```

As https://stackoverflow.com/users/80368/anand-shah commented